# composer network start: No valid responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to deploy a multiple organisations to Hyperledger fabric by following this tutorial -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org

Everything works as expected until I try to start the network:

```
composer network start -l "DEBUG" -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 -n block-aviation-network -V 0.0.1 -o endorsementPolicyFile=./tmp/composer/endorsement-policy.json -A SimonOrg1 -C SimonOrg1/admin-pub.pem -A SimonOrg2 -C SimonOrg2/admin-pub.pem -A SimonOrg3 -C SimonOrg3/admin-pub.pem
```

after which I get the following error:

```
    error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
```

I had a look a the following link (https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#information_source--composer-network-start-issues) which suggested to add the following as enviroment variable to the containers:

```
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=2400s
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=1600s
```

But I still go the same error as detailed above.

peer-base.yaml

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

services:
  peer-base:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_blockaviation
      #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=ERROR
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=2400s
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=1600s
      #- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=host
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
```

docker-compose-base.yaml

```
    # Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

services:

  orderer.blockaviation.com:
    container_name: orderer.blockaviation.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      #- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=host
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
    - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
    - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/blockaviation.com/orderers/orderer.blockaviation.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
    - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/blockaviation.com/orderers/orderer.blockaviation.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
    ports:
      - ${IP}:7050:7050

  peer0.org1.blockaviation.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.blockaviation.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.blockaviation.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.blockaviation.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.blockaviation.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=2400s
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=1600s
      #- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=host
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.blockaviation.com/peers/peer0.org1.blockaviation.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.blockaviation.com/peers/peer0.org1.blockaviation.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - ${IP}:7051:7051
      - ${IP}:7053:7053

  peer1.org1.blockaviation.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.blockaviation.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.blockaviation.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.blockaviation.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.blockaviation.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.blockaviation.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=2400s
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=1600s
      #- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=host
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.blockaviation.com/peers/peer1.org1.blockaviation.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.blockaviation.com/peers/peer1.org1.blockaviation.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls

    ports:
      - ${IP}:8051:7051
      - ${IP}:8053:7053

  peer0.org2.blockaviation.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.blockaviation.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.blockaviation.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.blockaviation.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.blockaviation.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org2.blockaviation.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=2400s
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=1600s
      #- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=host
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.blockaviation.com/peers/peer0.org2.blockaviation.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.blockaviation.com/peers/peer0.org2.blockaviation.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - ${IP}:9051:7051
      - ${IP}:9053:7053

  peer1.org2.blockaviation.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.blockaviation.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org2.blockaviation.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.blockaviation.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org2.blockaviation.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org2.blockaviation.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=2400s
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=1600s
      #- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=host
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.blockaviation.com/peers/peer1.org2.blockaviation.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.blockaviation.com/peers/peer1.org2.blockaviation.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - ${IP}:10051:7051
      - ${IP}:10053:7053

# ORGANISATION THREE

  peer0.org3.blockaviation.com:
    container_name: peer0.org3.blockaviation.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org3.blockaviation.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org3.blockaviation.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org3.blockaviation.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org3.blockaviation.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org3MSP
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=2400s
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=1600s
      #- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=host
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.blockaviation.com/peers/peer0.org3.blockaviation.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.blockaviation.com/peers/peer0.org3.blockaviation.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - ${IP}:11051:7051
      - ${IP}:11053:7053

  peer1.org3.blockaviation.com:
    container_name: peer1.org3.blockaviation.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org3.blockaviation.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org3.blockaviation.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org3.blockaviation.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org3.blockaviation.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org3MSP
      #- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=host
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=2400s
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=1600s
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.blockaviation.com/peers/peer1.org3.blockaviation.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.blockaviation.com/peers/peer1.org3.blockaviation.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - ${IP}:12051:7051
      - ${IP}:12053:7053
```

Commands used to deploy network:

```
mkdir channel-artifacts crypto-config

bash byfn.sh -m generate

bash byfn.sh -m up -s couchdb -a -t 5


mkdir -p ./tmp/composer/org1
mkdir -p ./tmp/composer/org2
mkdir -p ./tmp/composer/org3

awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}' crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.blockaviation.com/peers/peer0.org1.blockaviation.com/tls/ca.crt > ./tmp/composer/org1/ca-org1.txt
caOrg1="$(<./tmp/composer/org1/ca-org1.txt)"
echo "$caOrg1"

awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}' crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.blockaviation.com/peers/peer0.org2.blockaviation.com/tls/ca.crt > ./tmp/composer/org2/ca-org2.txt
caOrg2="$(<./tmp/composer/org2/ca-org2.txt)"
echo "$caOrg2"

awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}' crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.blockaviation.com/peers/peer0.org3.blockaviation.com/tls/ca.crt > ./tmp/composer/org3/ca-org3.txt
caOrg3="$(<./tmp/composer/org3/ca-org3.txt)"
echo "$caOrg3"

awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}' crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/blockaviation.com/orderers/orderer.blockaviation.com/tls/ca.crt > ./tmp/composer/ca-orderer.txt
caOrderer="$(<./tmp/composer/ca-orderer.txt)"
echo "$caOrderer"
export ORG1=./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.blockaviation.com/users/Admin@org1.blockaviation.com/msp
cp -p $ORG1/signcerts/A*.pem ./tmp/composer/org1
cp -p $ORG1/keystore/*_sk ./tmp/composer/org1

export ORG2=./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.blockaviation.com/users/Admin@org2.blockaviation.com/msp
cp -p $ORG2/signcerts/A*.pem ./tmp/composer/org2
cp -p $ORG2/keystore/*_sk ./tmp/composer/org2

export ORG3=./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.blockaviation.com/users/Admin@org3.blockaviation.com/msp
cp -p $ORG3/signcerts/A*.pem ./tmp/composer/org3
cp -p $ORG3/keystore/*_sk ./tmp/composer/org3


touch ./tmp/composer/org1/byfn-network-org1.json
touch ./tmp/composer/org2/byfn-network-org2.json
touch ./tmp/composer/org3/byfn-network-org3.json


composer card create -p ./tmp/composer/org1/byfn-network-org1.json -u PeerAdmin -c ./tmp/composer/org1/Admin@org1.blockaviation.com-cert.pem -k ./tmp/composer/org1/*_sk -r PeerAdmin -r ChannelAdmin -f PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1.card
composer card create -p ./tmp/composer/org2/byfn-network-org2.json -u PeerAdmin -c ./tmp/composer/org2/Admin@org2.blockaviation.com-cert.pem -k ./tmp/composer/org2/*_sk -r PeerAdmin -r ChannelAdmin -f PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2.card
composer card create -p ./tmp/composer/org3/byfn-network-org3.json -u PeerAdmin -c ./tmp/composer/org3/Admin@org3.blockaviation.com-cert.pem -k ./tmp/composer/org3/*_sk -r PeerAdmin -r ChannelAdmin -f PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org3.card


composer card import -f PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1.card --card PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1
composer card import -f PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2.card --card PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2
composer card import -f PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org3.card --card PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org3


composer network install --card PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 --archiveFile ../BlockAviation/dist/block-aviation-network.bna
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2 --archiveFile ../BlockAviation/dist/block-aviation-network.bna
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org3 --archiveFile ../BlockAviation/dist/block-aviation-network.bna


 touch ./tmp/composer/endorsement-policy.json

 cat << EOF > ./tmp/composer/endorsement-policy.json
 {
     "identities": [
         {
             "role": {
                 "name": "member",
                 "mspId": "Org1MSP"
             }
         },
         {
             "role": {
                 "name": "member",
                 "mspId": "Org2MSP"
             }
         }
     ],
     "policy": {
         "2-of": [
             {
                 "signed-by": 0
             },
             {
                 "signed-by": 1
             }
         ]
     }
 }
EOF


composer identity request -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 -u admin -s adminpw -d SimonOrg1
composer identity request -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2 -u admin -s adminpw -d SimonOrg2
composer identity request -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org2 -u admin -s adminpw -d SimonOrg3


composer network start -l "DEBUG" -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 -n block-aviation-network -V 0.0.1 -o endorsementPolicyFile=./tmp/composer/endorsement-policy.json -A SimonOrg1 -C SimonOrg1/admin-pub.pem -A SimonOrg2 -C SimonOrg2/admin-pub.pem -A SimonOrg3 -C SimonOrg3/admin-pub.pem
```

I had a look at the logs of my docker containers but I couldn't see any obvious errors. (see log for peer0.org1)

```
2018-04-27 13:47:43.662 UTC [dockercontroller] Start -> DEBU 8d6 start-could not find image <dev-peer0.org1.blockaviation.com-block-aviation-network-0.0.1-31fe9b4f843162ae50dcbb6bf4911fbdd8769fb314de85411475e43ee76433db> (container id <dev-peer0.org1.blockaviation.com-block-aviation-network-0.0.1>), because of <no such image>...attempt to recreate image
2018-04-27 13:47:43.663 UTC [chaincode-platform] generateDockerfile -> DEBU 8d7 
FROM hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:x86_64-0.4.6
ADD binpackage.tar /usr/local/src
LABEL org.hyperledger.fabric.chaincode.id.name="block-aviation-network" \
      org.hyperledger.fabric.chaincode.id.version="0.0.1" \
      org.hyperledger.fabric.chaincode.type="NODE" \
      org.hyperledger.fabric.version="1.1.0" \
      org.hyperledger.fabric.base.version="0.4.6"
ENV CORE_CHAINCODE_BUILDLEVEL=1.1.0
2018-04-27 13:47:43.745 UTC [util] DockerBuild -> DEBU 8d8 Attempting build with image hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:x86_64-1.1.0
2018-04-27 13:52:29.809 UTC [gossip/discovery] getDeadMembers -> WARN 8d9 Haven't heard from [10 94 61 126 168 3 233 141 146 255 32 24 59 157 112 91 199 47 185 79 219 186 21 43 174 78 212 36 58 249 239 248] for 26.6482049s
```

One thing I did notice was that my  fabric-ccenv containers were running in my bridge network rather than in my ba_multi_org_blockaviation network with all my other containers.

NETWORK DETAILS:

```
BA_multi_org simonmullaney$ docker network list
NETWORK ID          NAME                         DRIVER              SCOPE
dfc17755fb97        ba_multi_org_blockaviation   bridge              local
f79a2359276a        bridge                       bridge              local
1ea87e9a0bb4        host                         host                local
e22f1c0f8ead        none                         null                local
Simons-MBP:BA_multi_org simonmullaney$ docker inspect dfc17755fb97
[
    {
        "Name": "ba_multi_org_blockaviation",
        "Id": "dfc17755fb97e219bfb0d3069a95f1760e5a914e0bb596613b6b266e6880d080",
        "Created": "2018-04-30T14:02:57.360711604Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "0b954d9968aa160918b7672cb5bc07423cd1cd703973c6677f1c82d9fdfd057c": {
                "Name": "couchdb3",
                "EndpointID": "7aeed72f86e46e445753e5726abe53bec188eeef0ac30c2497e64e27cff24294",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "0f753b1cdd3ae2f864e22d5bc8e0dfbb944d703af0f848ac118e36029779af38": {
                "Name": "peer0.org1.blockaviation.com",
                "EndpointID": "3af255d328a9390a29e96617d451ed2d6b843dca5a88b6778c6234a02fd45d5b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:0d",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.13/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "2164fbac12736d56caef42644d07e381526020f6d4dcaddeea9c475a0a02f967": {
                "Name": "couchdb0",
                "EndpointID": "dfb0fbabf68cd8a1d1c29213dbb04e541bf855d54bd4e8aa748c67564d937db1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:08",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.8/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "353acf5a6f4b290b5b300f315f6a30a12dd23024c08fa2ae9b9966f4efc92d30": {
                "Name": "peer1.org1.blockaviation.com",
                "EndpointID": "e03fd033311a7516a5d5d9a89153eb45eba090bd73a4eb78f2bb4e7d45b7e9e9",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:0f",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.15/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "4f50fa5e3e68b10b792b5f466b939c26e748688a57fa117288a1bd6f0c8d5223": {
                "Name": "couchdb5",
                "EndpointID": "cf77a071036f7bca03358a5536490f7c34755ad393556195a7107de2d80c6708",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:07",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.7/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "55952da16c664679e75c5c33e2ec7d45ba20d6c6179cc68d6238c7d9af41c077": {
                "Name": "ca_peerOrg3",
                "EndpointID": "7055948f7462b637105dcc1b53d37d2e0a005b98503fec3503c465daa1dc9740",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "5e489993cb67bfd1df5ec7b30dbf4a463618957e8077b5463345564fc7928763": {
                "Name": "ca_peerOrg1",
                "EndpointID": "831a19a12cecf3b0e89443d50c70838688b14fb02e9a75ecdc7a8e51d93c9fef",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:0b",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.11/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "63708fe8a9eb09619f57af9c95b63ddbb16bc196fd8ff74f3a4b6b3170149381": {
                "Name": "peer1.org3.blockaviation.com",
                "EndpointID": "b9095de16ce6e9e73bfa751d6058ea441cd45cf5dac8e48ad902e22adcd6fcfb",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:11",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.17/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "8620a474e5c9886cc6274d708c97afd417e443c1b6d7857ff5a2c04e580a4210": {
                "Name": "peer0.org2.blockaviation.com",
                "EndpointID": "e452971c532f04c70b71922e86ba36941e0972099c96d8008fa93b9a8253f5bb",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:0c",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.12/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "89d7f5261bb4bcbe90a1b3169aa0e3f8875dcc448ae9c7a45c50b7d51fbc75df": {
                "Name": "couchdb4",
                "EndpointID": "66164991a57b4ebc557438e2e135f519a43f8de40d93df52f75ed48cd03c6114",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:09",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.9/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "9f66f64f2157e969283273470b1f5f0455cb165309f8bb61d63aa916e6bfd08b": {
                "Name": "peer1.org2.blockaviation.com",
                "EndpointID": "694966adbd07905d892c276bee84190e10997c2a706daee6db0b9650146421f0",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:10",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.16/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "a7ceadc414fd8bc073de5e8d372867e028829203abf5181df7942ce04234fe96": {
                "Name": "couchdb1",
                "EndpointID": "b0486b4b14d4c9ea1fcdb301a55558be8a9c285dbec0ed33c67141b7550174dc",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:06",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.6/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "b77c5432099968d29a56cbde7209c1417de74dd169e79762407ce5da77d4e0d4": {
                "Name": "ca_peerOrg2",
                "EndpointID": "de9889e88d0dc3f45239cc0a0ee1abe69b0f8aaf60419a6d3f92a5ecb89395f2",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:0a",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.10/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "bdc461a21b191a09829dd221ab813f9e1233be207b7635e3f081b639ed4fa274": {
                "Name": "orderer.blockaviation.com",
                "EndpointID": "1a9b37450ae5dacbaf359d3cddefd50acfc75f30b9d8015c334f3633956a471a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e4aeefaab1196824207f1a595635404c049ae15abacb773df8627d18876489b4": {
                "Name": "couchdb2",
                "EndpointID": "60b95f8970185d2329173634d2a393b2da31c368f893c674097f87d65ace1905",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ead8ab6770df47b51dcbeb4914c8eb9265cfd7c5c799ff49918a044945ff9171": {
                "Name": "peer0.org3.blockaviation.com",
                "EndpointID": "e9875505aff36628f7dad492e2158fa82ec3291272b32f5b9507cda425888bd2",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:0e",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.14/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
Simons-MBP:BA_multi_org simonmullaney$ docker inspect f79a2359276a
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "f79a2359276a533a516898109067f3f1f70188727d3c19322a74b51476c7ed8f",
        "Created": "2018-04-30T11:32:09.941991502Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "0ec4fe0586842b1562f7dbe5dc442922df8d298169a25c54515190764ec45f38": {
                "Name": "zealous_babbage",
                "EndpointID": "49b4949cf9bb5239d3ce94b6c8d436548178b33b0007b0c2ea78515c9ca50391",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "3b0b44a65ad6e945d0a684d10fc2d118ac778a3fc1bd456595f03f9f6ecea78b": {
                "Name": "friendly_curie",
                "EndpointID": "13160d1d380da4f485fab930938acadfc80867704fec93d50e4af647d63d5578",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "b8c6137baa9f53dafca0f20a75245ebf3f376c117a46d5004342186d303a9e05": {
                "Name": "ecstatic_cray",
                "EndpointID": "7dd9ddcf3f63b0b0c8ce3397ca98f7e41e7c3bb1b4e4edfda47899948f97f90b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c0e3a87b4b919d81fa2acea85dd14b71a589cd1b0eb92eb01c4e0695a431f9cf": {
                "Name": "pedantic_hodgkin",
                "EndpointID": "b614ee5cbbb708b43b71a52a6aec2069392d4b64d61f5135d88d233ba98b73ac",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c5a8a0d3f76be59635b09c421445337f1ed0436e4a056c7601c8e38abc11e975": {
                "Name": "wonderful_hawking",
                "EndpointID": "a0b08e0921662f6ea1d3e77d2eb0c99e7fd97ad98286e09b635c3fef9d8f459f",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:06",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.6/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Composer v0.19.1

Fabric v1.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the details.

Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed

This is an error I have previously associated with errors in the connection.json file, with the CLI being unable to 'find' the Fabric containers - usually because they are not started.  It is worth checking the connection.json file that you have the correct addresses, but I assume you have succeeded with `composer network install` for each of the Orgs.

This is a connection failure so you could well be on the right lines with the Docker networking.

Docker containers run on the default bridge unless you specify something different.  You set the network within the docker compose .yaml file, or on the docker run command line.

You can use `docker inspect bridge` and `docker inspect ba_multi_org_blockaviation` to see which containers are on which network.

You can also start a shell session on any container e.g. `docker exec -it peer0.org1.example.com /bin/sh` and then use `wget` to test connectivity on different addresses and ports - this should help identify the connection problem.

wget is not the perfect network testing tool, but it is installed already in the Fabric containers! I would suggest trying these examples on your ubuntu host machine to get a feel for successful and failed connections:

`wget www.ibm.com:80`

`wget www.ibm.com:9999`

`wget bad.bad.bad`

Then from within the various containers try commands such as

`wget peer0.org1.example.com:7051`

`wget peer0.org1.example.com:7053`

If you see wget errors such error "(Connection reset by peer)" that is actually a success for our simple addressing/port/connectivity test !  (we don't really want a web get we just want to know we can 'hit' the other address/port)

Comment: Thanks @RThatcher. All my containers are running in my ba_multi_org_blockaviation network except my fabric_ccenv containers. Do you know what command creates the fabric_ccenv containers? Is there any way I can pass the network name in that command to make sure they are all on the same network?

Comment: I tried what you outlined above, I could connect to peers and orderers but couldn't connect to the fabric_ccenv containers - I think they might be my problem

Comment: this line looks like the one that will specify the Network Name to the CC container:
`- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_blockaviation`  - first thought is are you setting COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME ? and second thought, why not just supply a literal of "ba_multi_org_blockaviation" for testing ?

Comment: I tried adding CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_blockaviation to my YAML file but my CC containers are still on my bridge network for some reason

Comment: How was the Docker network 'ba_multi_org_blockaviation' created?
And you can simply hardcode the network name as the value of CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE.  Taking a look at the network inspection you posted, it looks like ba_multi_org_blockaviation is not an attachable network either