# Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: could not find chaincode with name <NetworkName>

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Here is what I try to do :

- VM1 : CA, Orderer, Peer0, NodeServer1
- VM2 : Peer1, NodeServer2

If I create a card with server1 and a connection profile including only orderer, CA and **Peer1** , the card is able to ping the network.
If I create a card with server2 and a connection profile including only orderer, CA and **Peer2**, I am able to create the card but unable to ping the network with this card.
More info :

1) My VM are able to communication on any port. Internet link is not the pb.

2) If I use a connection.json including Ca, Orderer, Peer1 and Peer0, the card created on VM2 is working.

Any idea ?

You can ask if you need more info.

thx

Connection.json on VM1 :

```
{
"name": "hlfv1",
"x-type": "hlfv1",
"x-commitTimeout": 300,
"version": "1.0.0",
"client": {
    "organization": "Org1",
    "connection": {
        "timeout": {
            "peer": {
                "endorser": "300",
                "eventHub": "300",
                "eventReg": "300"
            },
            "orderer": "300"
        }
    }
},
"channels": {
    "composerchannel": {
        "orderers": [
            "orderer.example.com"
        ],
        "peers": {
            "peer0.org1.example.com": {}
        }
    }
},
"organizations": {
    "Org1": {
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "peers": [
            "peer0.org1.example.com"
        ],
        "certificateAuthorities": [
            "ca.org1.example.com"
        ]
    }
},
"orderers": {
    "orderer.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://<IP1>:7050"
    }
},
"peers": {
    "peer0.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://<IP1>:7051",
        "eventUrl": "grpc://<IP1>:7053"
    }
},
"certificateAuthorities": {
    "ca.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "http://<IP1>:7054",
        "caName": "ca.org1.example.com"
    }
}
```

}

Connection.json on VM2 :

```
{
"name": "hlfv1",
"x-type": "hlfv1",
"x-commitTimeout": 300,
"version": "1.0.0",
"client": {
    "organization": "Org1",
    "connection": {
        "timeout": {
            "peer": {
                "endorser": "300",
                "eventHub": "300",
                "eventReg": "300"
            },
            "orderer": "300"
        }
    }
},
"channels": {
    "composerchannel": {
        "orderers": [
            "orderer.example.com"
        ],
        "peers": {
            "peer1.org1.example.com": {}
        }
    }
},
"organizations": {
    "Org1": {
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "peers": [
            "peer1.org1.example.com"
        ],
        "certificateAuthorities": [
            "ca.org1.example.com"
        ]
    }
},
"orderers": {
    "orderer.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://<IP1>:7050"
    }
},
"peers": {
    "peer1.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpc://<IP2>:7051",
        "eventUrl": "grpc://<IP2>:7053"
    }
},
"certificateAuthorities": {
    "ca.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "http://<IP1>:7054",
        "caName": "ca.org1.example.com"
    }
}
```

}

```
docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
bad3e19266c6        bridge              bridge              local
bb28a60f158b        composer_default    bridge              local
8002ff68da75        host                host                local
f5c9ac2997e5        none                null                local



docker inspect composer_default
[
    {
        "Name": "composer_default",
        "Id": "bb28a60f158b4c61438b3792c0c2cd5c13d1aa3bbbd6c1cfe8dff88a0232efc1",
        "Created": "2018-05-31T13:56:28.314975468+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "<IP2>",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "868f282e3ae67ed3861e9e4729292019b220b3f04dfcf300395251223ba14b68": {
                "Name": "peer1.org1.example.com",
                "EndpointID": "1141dd4d1aa0ed6a4ec1e5dd103a3affa90a8344600969111af433f5ad396d59",
                "MacAddress": "<MACAddress>",
                "IPv4Address": "<IP2>",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "aa6579c58c1bd2bfde2491a083fc731f7fbc0ec44d609c2105ff6628be14bf15": {
                "Name": "couchdb1",
                "EndpointID": "dddb99538f49524ce5d68fb768cb73c0d96608f57e6fe743ddfc0023a63c6a3e",
                "MacAddress": "<MACAddress>",
                "IPv4Address": "<IP2>",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: sorry, but without any config metadata (connection profile info etc) - its difficult to know how to help you! One assumes you had a look at this tutorial https://discourse.skcript.com/t/setting-up-a-blockchain-business-network-with-hyperledger-fabric-composer-running-in-multiple-physical-machine/602 that is similar to your setup ?

Comment: I edited my question with connection.json. Be aware that VM1 has Peer0 and VM2 has Peer1

Comment: 1). The error in the HEADING of this question suggests that you have not done a `composer network install` of the business network (the missing chaincode) on the VM2 peer - or - you've not installed it with the right name. So you CAN ping on peer0 on VM1 but not the peer 1.  Suggests that you have not got resolution such that peer 2 can see containers on VM1 and vice versa (from VM1 to container on VM2).

Comment: 2) The error can ALSO suggest (as its a Fabric message :-) ) peer2 (ie if it IS indeed resolvable) is not JOINED the channel - so you should check that - if that's verified,  you can then easily `docker exec` into the peer to inspect what chaincodes are installed

Comment: 3) Finally,  Have you run these docker commands to check all containers are on the expected (and same) network bridge?  `docker network ls ` and  `docker inspect composer_default ` - some troubleshooting tips (eg. connectivity testing / resolution etc) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064302/composer-network-start-no-valid-responses-from-any-peers-response-from-attempt/50067199#50067199)

Comment: I updated my question with what you're asking. Be sure to check my 2). Do I need to install the network on VM2 too ? Actually, I am able to import card on VM2, check 2).

Comment: Moreover, I tried to install bna on VM2 (where there is only Peer1), and it said "The BN is already installed on all peers".