# Hyperledger composer over docker swarm

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, docker-swarm, hyperledger-composer

I have deployed hyperledger composer over docker swarm following this article https://medium.com/@drakshayani7/hi-i-have-deployed-hyperledger-composer-application-over-docker-swarm-f54089d2ed7a. Everything is working perfect. 
Now I'm going one step further by adding rest server with passport-google-strategy in the current docker swarm network.

But Its giving me error as "Exception: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: No peers available to query. last error was Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed Error: Error trying to ping. Error: No peers available to query. last error was Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed at _checkRuntimeVersions.then.catch (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:813:34) 
at  "

Currently in rest server card's connection.json file I have kept service names. I even tried host name and docker ip address. But still it showing the same error.

Can anyone please guide me on this...

Comment: As you'll see from the [Google OAUTH2 REST server tutorial(https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest) - resolution needed from the rest-server container, to the 'outside' Fabric nodes (ie docker containers ; REST server needs to know how to communicate with these on the NW). You can `docker exec` into it to test it out (see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064302/composer-network-start-no-valid-responses-from-any-peers-response-from-attempt/50067199#50067199) in this stack overflow for further detail on using `wget` etc to test connectivity)

Comment: Using wget command for orderer im getting correct response[connection reset]. for peers its refusing connection and for ca its saying not found. but im not getting why its saying connection refused.. What im missing. All the containers are up. And no error logs in any container..